# generics syntax map.entry

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I have a variable:

```
Class<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> clazz;
```

And I want to assign a class to it without instantiating anything. but compiler doesn't let me write:

```
Class<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> clazz = Map.Entry<String, Boolean>.class;
```

how can i do the assignment?

Comment: What do you mean by assigning a class to without instantiating anything ?! May be you need to assign `null` to it ?

Comment: What you're trying to do, doesn't make any sense to me. Can you please explain your intention?

Comment: i want to have an object of type Class assigned to my variable. i could do it with new Map.Entry().getClass (more-less) but i don't want to instantiate new object only to get its class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> clazz =
    (Class<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>)(Class<?>)Map.Entry.class;
```

Ahh, the joys of type erasure.

The Java compiler distinguishes between the types `Map.Entry` (raw) and `Map.Entry<String, Boolean>` (parameterized). Unfortunately, you can't add the type parameters in a type literal using `.class`. So you have to cast. But you can't do this directly; you'll have to take a 'detour' through `Class<?>`. I don't remember why, exactly, I'm sorry :).

Also, you'll get an 'unchecked' warning, which you can suppress, because you know (in this case) that the cast will always succeed. So:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> clazz =
    (Class<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>)(Class<?>)Map.Entry.class;
```

(No need to put the warning on the method where this assignment happens; you can just put it directly in front of the assignment.)

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Oh heck, I'm not going to pull out Eclipse to check your response.. I've been hit enough times by every one of these issues to recognize correct principles at work... upvote.

Comment: @RichardSitze Thanks! I guess this is Java's subtle way to tell people they shouldn't be doing this kind of nasty reflection stuff in the first place :).

Comment: they really add generics without a possibility to assign the parametrized .class? unbelievable! this solution is ugly as hell but it actually works and appears to be the only possible. thx

Comment: @piotrek Yep. It's because the JVM is not aware of the parameterized types at runtime. They did this for backward compatibility with older versions of Java, which was a good idea at the time, but quite inconvenient now that we're 8 years later.